# How can I avoid this Shiny uiOutput error?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny app that displays text with conditional highlighting to show how common sentiment analysis dictionaries would score that text. The app works when I use a simple example as the input string, but it throws "Error: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector" when I try using longer scraped strings instead. In both cases, the input to my text-annotating process is a length-one character vector, so I don't understand why it fails in the latter situation or how to fit it.

Here's a reproducible example. This works:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(rvest)

nrc_sentiments <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>%
    filter(sentiment == "negative" | sentiment == "positive") %>%
    mutate(color = recode(sentiment, positive = "Aqua", negative = "Yellow"))

example.text <- "We laughed, we cried, we sang, we dreamt of happier days to come and cursed the ones who abandoned us. I hate Mondays. I like beer."

ui <- mainPanel(fluidRow(uiOutput("thetextoutput")))

server <- function(input, output){

    output$thetextoutput <- renderUI({

        bag_of_words <- strsplit(example.text, " ")[[1]]

        lapply(bag_of_words, function(x) {

             col <- "White"

             if (tolower(x) %in% nrc_sentiments$word) {

                 col <- nrc_sentiments$color[which(nrc_sentiments$word == x)]

             }

             tags$span(style = paste("background-color:", col), x)

        })  

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If, however, I use the following line of code to generate the input string instead and then run the app with the same `ui` and `server` code as above, I get the aforementioned "Error: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector".

```
example.text <- read_html("https://www.usconstitution.net/const.txt") %>% html_text()
```

Any ideas on why this string breaks the app but the other one does not? I tried some simple stuff like removing dashes and carriage returns from the string before processing it, but that made no difference.

Comment: this is very strange, with the downloaded text, I ran the loop manually with subsets of 1000 words (0-1000, 1000-2000, etc.) and some of the words break everything down, such as "vote", "presentment"... Removing these words seems to solve the problem but I've no idea why. If you want to be convinced of that, take a subset of the text, run the ```strsplit``` and  ```lapply``` functions on it (out of shiny) and change the words that break the function (no more than 4 or 5 normally). The app should work when you run it with this corrected subset.

Comment: also, I've added some characters in ```strsplit```, it might help you: ```" |\n|\n\n|\\-|\\, |\\. |\\.\n\n|\\; ")[[1]]```

Comment: @bretauv, I need to keep searching for a solution that will generalize, but that's an intriguing lead, thank you.